# Erlang project can't launch on Windows generated by rebar

Tags: windows, erlang, rebar

I compiled an generate my project(which called eddy) on Windows with rebar successfully, but can not launch.

```
eddy.cmd start

erlsrv.exe: The service eddy_1 is not an erlsrv controlled service.
```

Frustrated...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before you can start the service, you have to install it:

```
eddy.cmd install
eddy.cmd start
```

If you just want to run it, use the console option:

```
eddy.cmd console
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you'll find your way here: [google search result](http://easyerl.blogspot.fr/2009/08/erlang-how-to-make-windows-service.html). Check your eddy.cmd file or any other command file called.